# Google Cloud Messaging Unique Key

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I've read in Google Cloud Messaging documentation that GCM key is unique per device and per application. If I uninstall and reinstall the application the key is always the same, ie, the key is calculated based on some device and application identifiers or the key will change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the key (called Registration ID) may change after you uninstall and re-install the app.

The following scenario will cause the ID to change :

1. un-install the app
2. send a GCM message to the device several times, until GCM server realizes that the app was uninstalled from the device
3. re-install the app

Comment: @notGeek No, I mean install the app again after previously un-installing it.

Comment: How can I remove the GCM key from my server when the application is uninstalled from the device? Right now I am receiving duplicate notifications after reinstalling the application because my server stored two identifiers as if they were from different devices. Thanks a lot

Comment: @notGeek When your server sends a notification with the old registration ID, the response from Google will contain a canonical registration ID, which is the new registration ID. When you get such a response you should delete the old registration ID.