# Google Cloud Messaging for Android - Is the sender id unique?

Tags: android

I am using the GMC Registration ID in my app identify that device.

I thought that it did not change and was unique to each app and device, but it seems that, sometimes, the Registration ID changes.

Do you know when does this happens? Also, is there anything that I can use as an unique id provided by android?

According to this: [Google Cloud Messaging Unique Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594948/google-cloud-messaging-unique-key)

It changes when you uninstall and install the app, but no when it is updated from the store. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should not use de GCM id to identify the device!
Read this entry: http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html